# Undefined redux props when refresh page in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, refresh, react-props

I'm having trouble getting datas from redux when I refresh my page

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState<string[]>(props.filters);

useEffect(() => {
    (() => {
      if (!_.isEqual(filters, props.filters)) {
        setFilters(props.filters);
      }
    })();
});
```

My filters are undefined even though when I check redux devtools, there is datas in filters.
I need to trigger an event in my front to display my filters.

Anyone have an idea please ?

Edit:

(if I click any element in my page it load my filters)

If I add a setTimeout on refresh it works but I'm not sure using setTimeout is a solution

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       setFilters(props.filters);
    }, 1500);
  }, []);
```

Comment: As per my understanding, On page refresh your redux store data will be set initial value(if you assigned). You must have to persist your store and retrieve before application load.

Comment: Like store it in localstorage ?

Comment: You can if your data is not more secure otherwise you can use  https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

<strike>May be you just missed returning the inner functions:</strike>

Or just call the `setFilters` like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!_.isEqual(filters, props.filters)) {
        setFilters(props.filters);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to return but no change, I still get an undefined value from props.filters

Comment: @Srid_vgd can you check the updated answer now? Also, take a look at the usage of `useEffect` in case you are missing something there: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I tried to call `setFilters` like you said, it works too (that reduce my code thanks!) but `props.filters` is still undefined. But I do store datas in my redux but I can't get it in the `useEffect` when I reload my page. (if I click any element in my page it load my filters)